# How to create a "time of week" form field in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I need to create a form field where the user can input a time in the week. For example "At 8:00 AM on Tuesday". I tried using a DateTimeType form field but can't seem to get it to do what I need.

Is there a way to do this using stock Symfony fields or do I need to create a custom form field type?

More specifically, I tried using DateTimeType and changing the 'date_format' option so it would only have weekday, hour and minute. The documentation links [this page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax) for the date/time format. So I used the string 'EEE H:M', only to get an exception saying that 'E' is not valid in the format.

Comment: Add some code snippets from what you tried to help others to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A datetime represents specific date and time, so it is not what you want.

I guess you go better with a select of days and one with times

and you could store the info combined in one field maybe `$dayofweek."_".$time`

Comment: More or less what I ended up doing, a 'day' select and 2 numeric inputs for hour and minute. Thanks for the suggestion.